# Bootstrap 3 Navbar fails to transition pages (displays "loading" idefinitely and shows content below the page)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have two .html pages with a lot of content copy-pasted between them.

They both have the navbar, exactly how it is in the demo with a few additional links.

When i click any links that are supposed to go to a new page, it attempts to fade out, but then it fades back in on the exact same page, with a "loading" header appended below, and the new page appended to the page!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid nav">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="employee.html" >Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Coming Soon">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Coming Soon">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="../Code/"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Coming Soon">Logout</a></li>
            <li><a href="employer.html">For Employers</a></li>
            <li><hr/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: using # for a link will take you to the same page. Plus you're missing the jQuery and CSS, what is doing the animation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was jQuery Mobile was conflicting. When I removed jQuery Mobile, everything worked fine.